# Script stops functioning after calling irsend() function in irlibrary!

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, ir, remote-control

I have the following script which checks if the user has pressed the numbers "770" or "769" continuously in the remote. The script works fine and displays all numbers. When I press the buttons "770" or "769" continuously the function powerOff() is called and I get no serial input.

```
/*
 * IRremote: IRrecvDemo - demonstrates receiving IR codes with IRrecv
 * An IR detector/demodulator must be connected to the input RECV_PIN.
 * Version 0.1 July, 2009
 * Copyright 2009 Ken Shirriff
 * http://arcfn.com
 */

#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

IRsend irsend;

decode_results results;

int intValue;
String strValue;
String str3;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    intValue = results.value;

    Serial.print("Integer value : ");
    Serial.println(intValue);


    strValue = String(intValue);
    Serial.print("String str : ");
    Serial.println(strValue);

    Serial.print("Length : ");
    Serial.print(strValue.length());
    Serial.println();


    if(strValue.length() <= 1){
      str3 += strValue;
      Serial.println(str3);
       // Receive the next value
   }

    delay(200);
    irrecv.resume();
  }
  //Serial.println(str3);
  if(str3.endsWith("770")){
    powerOff();
    str3 = "";
  }
  else if(str3.endsWith("769")){
    powerOff();
    str3 = "";
  }

  else{}
  //powerOff();
}

void powerOff(){
    irsend.sendRC6( 0xC0000C, 24);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you should be calling `irrecv.enableIRIn()` after sending, not `irrecv.resume()`. Sorry for suggesting the wrong thing on IRC before :-)